# Can a figcaption be restricted to the width of a responsively sized image?

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<figure>
<img alt="Sun" src="sun.gif" width="256" height="256" />
<figcaption>The Sun - a sinister and destructive force. Image from
the SOHO research facility.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If I want the text to wrap to the width of the image, I need this CSS:

```
figure {
    display: table;
    width: 1px;
}
```

If I want the image to be "responsive" — that is, be no bigger than the viewport — I need this CSS too:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

But combining these two results in a terrible mess! Now that the `img`'s parent has an explicit width set, the `max-width` causes the whole figure to be really, really tiny (although not quite `1px`).

So is it possible to use CSS (2 or 3) to achieve **both** an image caption wrapped to no wider than the image, and an image no wider than the viewport?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I came across the same issue and was able to come up with [a fairly neat solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/ya913c3t/), inspired by [this](https://github.com/milohuang/reverie/pull/81).

HTML:

```
<figure>
   <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x150" alt="" />
   <figcaption>Make me as long as you like</figcaption>
</figure>​
```

CSS:

```
figure {
   display: table;
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: .875em;
   
}

figure img {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
}

figcaption {
   display: table-caption;
   caption-side: bottom;
   background: #fff;
   padding: 0 5px 5px;
}​
```

This ensures the `figcaption` does not exceed the width of the `figure`, whilst allowing you to keep `max-width` on the image. Works in all good browsers and IE8+.

The figure's width will be whatever the native width of the image is, unless that width is restricted in some other way.

Comment: It gets a little complicated in this context (using table for the layout), but in general `max-width: 100%` is used for responsive designs to ensure that images never exceed the width of their container, breaking the layout. If our wrapper or figure is fluid rather than fixed then this becomes important. See [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images). In this instance you might want to have other styles or a fixed width on the figure for example.

Comment: Not sure if this was just me but I found I had to add: width: 100%; to the figcaption selector, otherwise it was really narrow and didn't span the width of the image.

Comment: This does not seem to actually work. In order for the image to be responsive (in this context meaning, that it is scaled down to the figure's parent's size), you would additionally need `figure { max-width:100%; }`. However, this does not work in conjunction with `display:table;`. See http://jsfiddle.net/xvcLknr2/ (and scale down the viewport on the lower right)
Am I missing something?

Comment: @Spooky - what browser are you using? Your example works perfectly for me (with or without the `max-width`).

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez - FireFox 35.0.1. It also does not work in Internet Explorer 11. It _does_ work in Chrome (39.0.2171.65) and its Android counterpart.

Comment: @Spooky - interesting, cheers. I could have sworn that I tested this cross-browser (but it was more than a year ago now and I can't remember what I ate last night...). Anyway, I've made a small edit to the answer and tested this working in Firefox 35 and IE11. Let me know if that works in your case.

Comment: Cool, yes that works :). So disregarding any default browser style resets etc., the gist of the code is this: http://jsfiddle.net/a195rfqu/

Comment: Well, there is another problem now. I just noticed that, with these styles, the `<figure>`'s height will not include the `<figcaption>`, only the `<img>`. This could be worked around with of course, but it's still not a general solution.

Comment: @Spooky - I don't understand, what is the issue?

Comment: With these table stylings applied, the `<figcaption>` is not part of the `<figure>` anymore, so to speak. e.g. if you wanted to style all the `<figure>`s and its captions in a way, that it has it's own background color and border for example, you cannot do that anymore. See http://jsfiddle.net/0xn0c747/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/oqxp0cvp/ for example.

Comment: Ah I see - it's a funny one. `<figcaption>` behaves like `<caption>`, which is then positioned visually 'outside' of the parent table (though the height returned with JS includes it). Knowing that this behaviour is consistent, you should be able to [recreate the same appearance](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/2zpm8n85/) for most designs (or include a wrapper `<div>` as a last resort).

Comment: Well yes, it works for the border, but in general it restricts you in the way you can style the elements, without introducing additional mark up.

Comment: @Spooky - show me a design that you can't achieve with this: I like a challenge! You're right, there may be instances where additional markup is necessary, but I've used this on numerous sites of varying styles with no problems.

Comment: I'd just add:
```
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
```
To have the caption aligned in the centre of the image.

Answer (score 4):

> So is it possible to use CSS (2 or 3) to achieve both an image caption
>   wrapped to no wider than the image, and an image no wider than the
>   viewport?

Yes. Just use viewport units on the `img` - `max-width: 100vw;` instead of % - `max-width: 100%;`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/x20vc1n4/5/)

**Just for completeness:**

There are 2 other techniques to get the text to wrap to the width of the image:

1) Set `display: table-caption;` on the `figcaption`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/x20vc1n4/6/)

2) Set `width: min-content` on the `figure`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/x20vc1n4/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Because we have flexbox today, this might work for too. The following will auto adjust based on image width, so do not set hardcoded values within the stylesheet. (Yuk!) Be sure to follow today's best practices and make sure images have both, height and width attributes.

```css
figure {
float: left;
margin-right: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
display: inline-flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

figcaption {
width: min-content;
flex: 1; 
}

figure > img {
flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is image scaling important? If not, then consider using background images.

**PURE CSS**:

```
<figure>
<div class="caption">
<figcaption>The Sun - a sinister and destructive force. Image from
the SOHO research facility.</figcaption>
</div>
</figure>
<style type="text/css">
figure{display:table;width:1px;position:relative;}
figure div.caption{
background:url(sun.gif) no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
width:256px;
height:256px;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

**CSS WITH INLINE STYLING:**

```
<figure>
<div class="caption" style="background:url(sun.gif) no-repeat 0 0 scroll;width:256px;height:256px;">
<figcaption>The Sun - a sinister and destructive force. Image from
the SOHO research facility.</figcaption>
</div>
</figure>
<style type="text/css">
figure{display:table;width:1px;position:relative;}
figure div.caption{position:absolute;}
</style>
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean I'd need a CSS declaration for each image?

Comment: It would, yes. If you were planning on rendering the HTML in a server-side loop, you could always set the background-image and dimensions with inline styling to save time (see second example). Either way, if you want the caption width to be bounded by the image dimensions, those settings are going to have to be made by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Super old question, but I am currently in the same situation and I think I have found a very easy solution.  Admittedly I have only tested this in the latest versions which at this time are:
IE 11
FF 37
Chrome 40

```
<figure>
   <img>
   <figcaption>
</figure>

figure {
   display: table;
   width: 50px; /* Set this to the minimum caption width */
}
```

And that's it.
I don't know if it's a quirk that will be fixed in future but it works very well right now.  If the image is larger than 50px, the figure and figcaption will automatically resize.  If it is less than 50px, the caption stay 50px;

Comment: This is very similar to what the OP was doing. He said that solution was not acceptable because the design needs to be "responsive". It breaks as soon as you add the responsive CSS:

`img {
    max-width: 100%;
}`

How do you ensure the design is responsive? How do you make it look acceptable on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

> If I want the text to wrap to the width of the image, I need this CSS: 
>   [...]

Instead of hardcoding a size use `min-content`.

```css
figure {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 3px;
}
figure>figure {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100" alt="An image of a bunny rabbit."/>
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum  </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100"  alt="An image of a bunny rabbit." />
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100" alt="An image of a bunny rabbit."/>
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, molestiae, similique ullam labore soluta autem </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure>
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100" alt="An image of a bunny rabbit."/>
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, molestiae, similique ullam labore soluta autem placeat officia </figcaption>
 </figure>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about "min-content" (or "max-content", "fit-content"). Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work with "responsive design" css. See OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If using Bootstrap you can easily fix the problem by setting breakpoint widths on , e.g. class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-4". Both the image and its caption will nicely fit in the given sizes, and if the caption is too long for its image width it will wrap appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Keeps the image centered, which I want, and seems fully responsive.  Apologies in advance for not being able to figure out how to get the code font right.  As I said worked for me; no guarantee of course that it will work for you.

```
   <figure style="float:none;margin:auto">
                         <img style="max-height: 400px; max-width: 350px;margin:auto;" src="images/pp-improved-studio-shot-300pxw.jpg">  
                        <figcaption style="max-width:400px;">                        
                            The world standard for reliable solvent resistant touchup pens for all industries.                           
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
```